Output from linux tree command in minted
I'm trying to put the output of the linux tree command in minted. Now I'm using the listing from this stackexchange post but I want to use minted instead like the below image:

My latex code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm, left=2cm, bottom=4cm, footskip=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{tree}{
literate=
    {├}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {└}{{\smash{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1.5ex}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {─}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}}}1 
    {│}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{0pt}}}}1 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=tree]
    .
    ├── README.md
    ├── public
    │   ├── logo.svg
    │   └── image.png
    ├── src
    │   ├── App.tsx
    │   ├── assets
    │   │   └── components
    │   │       ├── About.tsx
    │   │       ├── Contact.tsx
    │   │       ├── NavBar.tsx
    │   └── main.tsx
    └── styles.css
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As long as your monofont contains the necessary symbols, you could directly use them in minted:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm, left=2cm, bottom=4cm, footskip=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=text,
  minted options={fontsize=\offinterlineskip},
  listing only
}
    .
    ├── README.md
    ├── public
    │   ├── logo.svg
    │   └── image.png
    ├── src
    │   ├── App.tsx
    │   ├── assets
    │   │   └── components
    │   │       ├── About.tsx
    │   │       ├── Contact.tsx
    │   │       ├── NavBar.tsx
    │   └── main.tsx
    └── styles.css
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}


(to find out which monofonts contains these symbols, you can use the command line tool albatross, e.g. albatross ├)

You are right! The problem was just the font that don't support the tree symbols. Thanks, your solution is much simpler.

I manage to solve it using a python script.
First, add the following in your preamble.tex
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
% colourful minted box config
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{inputminted}{\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{inputminted}{\end{tcolorbox}}

% minted tree configuration
\newcommand{\TreeBranch}{% ├
\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}%
\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\TreeEnd}{% └
\smash{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1.5ex}}}%
\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{1pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\TreeLine}{% ─
\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\TreeVert}{% │
\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}%
\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1ex}{0pt}}%
}

Then create a new python file with the following code:
replacements = {
'├': r'\TreeBranch',
'└': r'\TreeEnd',
'─': r'\TreeLine',
'│': r'\TreeVert',
'  ': r'  ',
}

with open('source.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

for char, command in replacements.items():
    content = content.replace(char, f'|{command}|')

with open('processed_source.tex', 'w') as file:
    file.write(content)

Save your tree output in source.txt and call the python script. It will generate the minted body in a file called processed_source.tex
You can use the generated tex code inside minted like this:
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{text}
.
|\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| README.md
|\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| public
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| logo.png
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeEnd||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| image.png
|\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| src
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| App.tsx
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| assets
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeVert||  | |\TreeEnd||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| components
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeVert||  |     |\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| About.tsx
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeVert||  |     |\TreeBranch||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| Contact.tsx
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeVert||  |     |\TreeEnd||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| NavBar.tsx
|\TreeVert||  | |\TreeEnd||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| main.tsx
|\TreeEnd||\TreeLine||\TreeLine| styles.css

\end{minted}


Seem complicated but the tex code is autogenerated by the script. Hope this help.

Instead of \BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]}     \AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}} \BeforeBeginEnvironment{inputminted}{\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]}     \AfterEndEnvironment{inputminted}{\end{tcolorbox}} you could use a tcblisting
